# Javascript for showing Div on click using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I have a `<div>` in my page like this:

```
 <div class="errordiv" style="display: none;">Username is empty</div>
```

I have an input field and a button like this:

```
<input type="textbox" id="txt1" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn1" onclick="validate();" />
```

I have tried this,

```
function validate() {
    //alert('hi');
    var inptextbox = document.getElementById('txt1');
    //alert('level zero');
    var errorMsg = document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv').item();
    //alert('level ground');
    if (inptextbox.value == '') {
        //alert('hi2');
        errorMsg.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        errorMsg.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The above js code is not working. I am not getting the level ground alert. I don't know what is missing.

P.S : I don't want Jquery as my page has some restriction to use library files.

Comment: It will be good, if some one can show me some working fiddle...

Comment: `var errorMsg = document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv').item();` replace `.item()` by `[0]`: `var errorMsg = document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv')[0];`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté `.item()` is fine

Comment: I find `[0]` more readable and less error-prone, but if it works as it is, alright.

Comment: @Musa Also, are you sure it works? [`.item()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList.item) expects an index argument and is throwing a `NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments` error on Firebug when called without passing an argument. http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5M6Tu/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It worked in webkit developer tool, I didn't check firefox

Comment: I didn't check on Webkit before, yup weirdly enough it works on Webkit but still crashes on Firefox. Hence I go for the `[0]` or `.item(0)`. `=]`

Comment: Above code i not working in IE7. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false in validate to stop the form from submitting, which reloads the page

EDIT

added polyfill for  `getElementsByClassName` with support for IE7 from https://gist.github.com/2299607

```
// Add a getElementsByClassName function if the browser doesn't have one
// Limitation: only works with one class name
// Copyright: Eike Send http://eike.se/nd
// License: MIT License
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
  document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
    var d = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
    if (d.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
      return d.querySelectorAll("." + search);
    }
    if (d.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
      pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
      elements = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
      while ((i = elements.iterateNext())) {
        results.push(i);
      }
    } else {
      elements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
      pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}

function validate() {
    //alert('hi');
    var inptextbox = document.getElementById('txt1');
    //alert('level zero');
    var errorMsg = document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv')[0];
    //alert('level ground');
    if (inptextbox.value == '') {
        //alert('hi2');
        errorMsg.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    } else {
        errorMsg.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the item syntax correction, that's the only thing that could be crashing it from OP's posted code imo.

Comment: @Spencer I added a polyfill for getElementsByClassName with support for IE7

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in chrome. This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzpb5/).

`document.getElementsByClassName` will not work for some old browsers, check [here](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname).

Comment: So what is the solution for this? I need to use only getElementByClassName. Why becoz, the errordiv is generating from the server.

Answer (score 0):

First off you'll need to return a value from your function to stop the page posting back if a validation even occurs, change your HTML to:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn1" onclick="return validate();" />
```

Then your script to:

```
function validate() {
    var inptextbox = document.getElementById('txt1');
    var errorMsg = document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv').item();

    if (inptextbox.value == '') {
        errorMsg.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could do with more info - what version of IE are you using, is it in compatibility mode, what's the actual error message you're getting?  Try using an indexer so change your line from document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv').item(); to: document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv')[0];

Comment: It is not working in IE7. Also my code is set to document.getElementByClassName('errordiv')[0]; - Any Help?

Comment: OK make sure your method name is EXACTLY document.getElementsByClassName('errordiv')[0] (plural), if this still doesn't work try using document.getElementsBySelector('.errordiv')[0] instead.